# Message: System error: -1072896658 ---- Problem with IE browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser

Am using IE8, in an search function when i search for a Order #, if there is a match it will appear in a pop along with block-Ui... this works fine in all browser except in IE only a blank pop up will appear and no search results displayed and got browser error below, for pop am using Ajax and Jquery Block-UI.

```
     **Webpage error details**

    User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1;
 Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729;
 .NET CLR 3.0.30729;
     Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2)
        Timestamp: Thu, 14 Apr 2011 06:29:56 UTC


        Message: System error: -1072896658.

        Line: 1
        Char: 1
        Code: 0
        URI: http://176.188.1.22:7777/web/Order.jsp
```

anybody know what `System error: -1072896658` means and how to solve..........?

Thank you.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue Solve:

Error message was due to contentType decleration in page imports in JSP

i was using

```
contentType="text/html; charset=UTF8"
```

in header of the page and now changed to

```
contentType="text/html;  charset=utf-8"
```

UTF8 to utf-8

Thank you....